# Python: When finding the product of a large array, how best to reduce floating point error?

Tags: python, numpy, precision, floating-accuracy

Suppose I have a large array with a bunch of floats in it, and I need to find the product while losing as little precision as possible to floating point errors:

```
import numpy as np
randoms = np.random.uniform(0.5, 1.61, 10000)
print(randoms[0:10])

array([ 1.01422339,  0.65581167,  0.8154046 ,  1.49519379,  0.96114304,
    1.20167417,  0.93667198,  0.66899907,  1.26731008,  1.59689486])
```

A presumably bad approach is to loop through the array and iteratively multiply. This will obviously have an error that compounds with each multiplication, so should be avoided if possible:

```
product_1 = 1
for i in randoms:
    product_1 = product_1 * i
print(product_1)

64355009.758539267
```

The next method is to use `numpy`'s built-in `prod` function, however this returns the exact same value as above, indicating that this is how `prod` is actually computing it:

```
product_2 = np.prod(randoms)
print(product_2)

64355009.758539267

print(product_1 == product_2)

True
```

A third way is to compute the logarithm of every term, sum them, and exponentiate at the end. Each logarithm is computed separately so there isn't the same compounding of the error, but the logarithm process and the exponentiation process both introduce some error themselves. In any case it produces a different answer:

```
product_3 = np.exp(np.sum(np.log(randoms)))
print(product_3)

64355009.758538999

print(product_3 == product_1)

False
```

I know that I'm not losing that much precision in this example, but for what I actually need to do, the compounding errors do end up causing troubles, enough that I'm considering using a package that can do symbolic / arbitrary precision computation. So, which method is the best here? Are there other ways I haven't considered?

Comment: One of the other ways you haven't considered is `NumPy`'s `cumprod` which stands for cumulative product. That's what you are doing basically. Just take the last element `[-1]` as `product_1 = np.cumprod(randoms)[-1]`. You can compare your answer

Comment: Look at Python's decimal and fractions libraries

Comment: I deleted my answer because `print(product_3 == product_1)` gives me `False`. `print(product_4 == product_2)` and `print(product_4 == product_1)` results in `True` where `product_4` is the result using `np.cumprod()`. It seems `log` and `exp` are the culprits for varying precision.

Comment: Even if you use `decimal` and do `from decimal import *` and then `getcontext().prec = 20`, it still results in `False`. It depends now what precision you want.

Comment: Yes, but I can repeat the calculation at different levels of precision and interrogate the outputs to see at which digit they begin to diverge.

Comment: I already checked it from `prec = 1` to `prec = 30`. The answer is always coming out to be `False`

Comment: That's not what I meant; it may come out differently, but I can calibrate it such that the final answer has the level of precision that I want.

Comment: Yes, that's possible. I used `round(product_1, 20)` and `round(product_3, 20)`. Depending on the random numbers, it shows sometimes `True` and sometimes `False`. That is self explanatory since you do not have any lower/upper bound for the product

Comment: What does numerical analysis say?  Does the order of evaluation of products matter?  I know there's a lot of theory regarding sums, especially when negative and positive elements can nearly cancel each other out.

Comment: My intuition says that the errors from the logarithms won't tend to cancel out when summed because of Jensen's Inequality (i.e. log of a mean is not the mean of logs), though I'm happy to be proved wrong here.

Comment: A few other things to play with.  `.astype('float128')`.  Use `math.fsum` to sum the logs.  Test dependence on order with `np.sort`, or reversing `[::-1]`, or shuffling.

Comment: `float128` is platform-dependent I think; I tested it with `finfo` and it's the same precision as `np.float` for me.

Comment: When you say the error “compounds” with each multiplication, what do you mean? Your later comment about errors not canceling when summed suggests you think the compounding is one-way. In fact, the rounding errors from either addition or multiplication will sometimes be upward, sometimes downward. I can’t immediately rule out some statistical bias due to numerical details, but I would not expect adding logarithms to have notably better error properties than multiplying the numbers, especially given the additional errors of taking the logarithms and exponentials.

Comment: I mean that even if the expectation of the total error is zero (not at all guaranteed btw), its variance increases with each operation. And yes, I wasn't sure whether the logarithm approach or the repeated multiplication approach was better, hence my asking the question in the first place.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I tried some experiments. The code is below but first some comments.

It is possible to compute the result exactly by converting the values into exact rational numbers, computing the product exactly, and then performing a final conversion to a float. It can be done with the `fractions` module included with Python but it will eventually get very slow. I used the `gmpy2` module for faster rational arithmetic.

There are some subtleties with the formatting of binary floating-point values for display. Recent versions of Python return the shortest possible decimal string that will result in the original value. `numpy` floats have a different formatting. And so does the `gmpy2.mpfr` type. And `Decimal` obviously used a different formatting rule. So I always convert the result calculated to a Python float.

In addition to the user-definable decimal precision of the `Decimal` type, I also used `gmpy2.mpfr` since it supports user-definable binary precision.

The program outputs several values:

- Sequential multiplication using 53-bit precision (IEEE 64-bit format).
- Exact value using rational arithmetic.
- Using Decimal with 28 decimal digits of precision.
- Using Decimal with a user-specified precision.
- Using mpfr with a user-specified precision.
- Using a recursive multiplication method to minimize the number of multiplications.

Here is the code. You can modify the `Decimal` and `mpfr` precision and test the accuracy.

```
import numpy as np
from gmpy2 import mpq, mpfr, get_context, round2
from decimal import Decimal, getcontext

randoms = np.random.uniform(0.5, 1.61, 10000)

# Sequential multiplication using 53-bit binary precision.

product_1 = 1
for i in randoms:
    product_1 = product_1 * i
print("53-bit binary:     ", float(product_1))

# Exact value by converting all floats to fractions and then a final
# conversion to float. Uses gmpy2 for speed.

product_2 = 1
for i in randoms:
    product_2 = product_2 * mpq(i)
print("exact using mpq:   ", float(mpfr(product_2, precision=53)))

# Decimal math with 28 decimal digits (~93 bits of precision.)

product_3 = 1
for i in randoms:
    product_3 = product_3 * Decimal(i)
print("Decimal(prec=28):  ", float(product_3))

# Choose your own decimal precision.

getcontext().prec=18
product_4 = 1
for i in randoms:
    product_4 = product_4 * Decimal(i)
print("Decimal(prec=%s):   %s" % (getcontext().prec, float(product_4)))

# Choose your own binary precision.

get_context().precision = 60
product_5 = 1
for i in randoms:
    product_5 = product_5 * mpfr(i)
print("mpfr(precision=%s): %s" % (get_context().precision, float(product_5)))

# Recursively multiply pairs of numbers together.

def rmult(d):
    if len(d) == 1:
        return d[0]
    # If the length is odd, extend with 1.
    if len(d) & 1:
        d.append(1)
    temp = []
    for i in range(len(d)//2):
        temp.append(d[2*i] * d[2*i+1])
    return rmult(temp)

print("recursive 53-bit:  ", float(rmult(list(randoms))))
```

As a rough guideline, as the number of multiplications increase, the intermediate precision will need to increase. Rational arithmetic will effectively give you infinite intermediate precision.

How critical is it that the result is 100% accurate?